How to fetch multiple text in the next line without whitespace using app script
I have a channel in slack where automated message is posted. The message looks like this:

A ticket is submitted by: @abc
Request Title test
Requested For @xyz
Requested system? MMM
See here for the ticket.

What i need to do is to fetch the system name 'MMM' or there can be multiple system name separated by comma.
I am trying the following appscript code but this is not fetching anything:
function extractData(message) {
  const regexRequestedSystem = /Requested system?\n(.*?)$/s;
  const requestedSystemMatch = regexRequestedSystem.exec(message);

  return {
    requestedSystem: requestedSystemMatch ? requestedSystemMatch[1].trim() : null,
    messageLink: `https://slack.com/app_redirect?channel=${channelId}&message_ts=${message.ts}`,
  };
}

Could you please help me with the regex syntax?
Thank you!!
I tried this syntax:
const regexRequestedSystem = /Requested system?\n(.*?)$/s;
but this is not fetching anything. I need to fetch the 'MMM' only like I said before.

Why  are you trying to match a newline?

@Thefourthbird I needed to check the condition. I want to do it only when the condition match. I have already got the solutions in the answers below.

In that case you could mark an answer as accepted.

Here you can get Requested system Names in an array


const text = `
A ticket is submitted by: @abc

Request Title test

Requested For @xyz

Requested system? MMM, LLL, KKK

See here for the ticket.
`;

const regex = /Requested system\?\s*([\w\s,]+)$/m; // Match until the end of the line
const match = text.match(regex);

if (match) {
    const systems = match[1].split(',').map(name => name.trim()); // Splits by commas and trims spaces
    console.log(systems); // Outputs: ['MMM', 'LLL', 'KKK']
} else {
    console.log("No match found");
}




Try this approach
I used Google Docs to give as a sample for your question and here's some modification on your code.
Regex const regex = /Requested system\?\s*(.+)/; 
This part is a capturing group () that matches one or more characters (.+) after the spaces.
This will capture everything that follows "Requested system?" in the document, which could be the list of systems or any other content.
Modified Script
function extractRequestedSystem() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const bodyText = doc.getBody().getText();
  const regex = /Requested system\?\s*(.+)/;
  const match = bodyText.match(regex);
  
  if (match) {
    const requestedSystem = match[1].trim();
    Logger.log(`Requested System: ${requestedSystem}`);
  } else {
    Logger.log('No match found');
  }
}

Sample Validation


Reference

REGEX

